# Redirect all folder traffic to an specific file via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all traffic of directory...

`https://subdomain.mydomain.com/folder/` to `https://subdomain.mydomain.com/folder/myfile.html`

I have an htaccess file into directory "folder" with this content...

`Redirect 302 / /myfile.html`

But when I type `https://subdomain.mydomain.com/folder/` it redirects to `https://subdomain.mydomain.com/myfile.htmlfolder/`

So, what is the correct way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Redirect or rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code inside `folder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^myfile\.html$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^ myfile.html [L]
```